# Python code for Second Order ODE Initial Value problem using Finite Difference methods

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, initial-value-problems, python, finite-differences

I am trying to solve the following ODE $$\begin{aligned} & y^{\prime \prime}+2 y^{\prime}+y=0 \\ & y(0)=2 \quad y^{\prime}(0)=-1 \\ & 0 \leqslant x \leqslant 1 \end{aligned}$$
Using central FD, I can write $$\frac{y_{i+1}-2 y_i+y_{i-1}}{h^2}+2 \frac{y_{i+1}-y_{i-1}}{2 h}+y_i=0$$ which I have simplied to $$(1+h) y_{i+1}+\left(h^2-2\right) y_i+(1-h) y_{i-1}=0$$ I am struggling to fit the second boundary condition into the set of resulting equations. Using central FD, I think I can derive $$\begin{aligned} & \frac{y_2-y_0}{2 h}=-1 \\ & y_0=y_2+2 h\end{aligned}$$ However, I am not sure how to make use of this condition. Can you please guide me ?

The analytic solution to the ODE is given as $y(x)=2 e^{-x}+x e^{-x}$

Thanks

Based on whpowell96's suggestion, I will create the system of equations as follows. I have removed the python code for now.
Does this look correct?
Thank you.

Assuming N = 10

$$
\begin{aligned}
& h=0.125 , h^2=0.016, 1-h=0.875 \\
& 1.125 y_2-1.984 y_1=-1.75 \\
& 1.125 y_3-1.984 y_2+0.875 y_1=0 \\
& 1.125 y_{11}-1.984 y_{10}+0.875 y_9=0
\end{aligned}
$$

AND from $B C$
$$
1 y_2+0 y_1-1 y_0=-2 h
$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
-1.984 & 1.125 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0.875 & -1.984 & 1.125 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0.875 & -1.984 & 1.125 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0.875 & -1.984 & 1.125 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0.875 & -1.984 & 1.125 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.875 & -1.984 & 1.125 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.875 & -1.984 & 1.125 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.875 & -1.984 & 1.125 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.875 & -1.984 & 1.125 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.875 & -1.984 & 1.125\\
-1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
y_1 \\
y_2 \\
y_3 \\
y_4 \\
y_5 \\
y_6 \\
y_7 \\
y_8 \\
y_9 \\
y_{10} \\
y_{11} \\
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
-1.75\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
-0.25\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: This is a simple linear DE with constant coefficients. Just solve $x^{2}+2x+1=0$ to get $x =-1$ as the only solution. This makes $e^{-x}, xe^{-x}$ as linearly independent solutions. You can refer to any book on ODE for this.

Comment: I am required to use central Finite Difference methods unfortunately.

Comment: The discretization of the ODE applies to $y_i$ associated with internal points of the region. You need the boundary conditions to account for behavior at the endpoints.

Comment: The two boundary conditions are provided in my question, y(0) and yprime(0) are given.

Comment: Let's say there are $N$ $y$ values: $y_0... y_{N-1}$. You need $N$ equations to solve for those $N$ unknowns. $N-2$ equations are provided by the recursion relation $(1+h)y_{i-1} + (h^2-2)y_i + (1-h)y_i=0$ you've correctly derived. The boundary conditions provide the remaining 2 equations on the left boundary: $y_0 = 2$ and $y_0 = y_2 + 2h$ (or perhaps $y_0 = y_1 + h$). Now you have a linear system of $N$ equations in $N$ unknowns of the form $A\vec{y}=\vec{b}$, which can solved for the vector $\vec{y}$ by standard methods.

Comment: Regarding your latest edit, you are solving for variables you know are fixed. Eliminate them from your system of equations and set up a linear system only for the unknown variables, $y_1,\dots,y_n$. You are setting a matrix coefficieint equal to a $y$ value in the latest edit.

Comment: Also you are adding `b[0]` to the value of the solution? Write out the system of equations on paper with knowns on the right and unknowns on the left then try to construct that system in Python.

Answer (score 3):

The way to do this that achieves the best accuracy is via the *ghost point method*. Label the nodes such that $y_0$ is at $x=0$. The discretized boundary conditions read
$$
\begin{aligned}
y_0 &= 2 \\
\frac{y_{1} - y_{-1}}{2h} &= -1.
\end{aligned}
$$
Here we have introduced an extra variable, $y_{-1}$ which corresponds to the function value one node to the left of the domain. Since the function is not defined there, it is called a *ghost node*. We won't actually evaluate it, but will merely use it to inform our algebra.

Now consider the difference equation at $x=0$:
$$
(1+h)y_1 + (h^2-2)y_0 + (1-h)y_{-1} = 0.
$$
Again, we are using the ghost point $y_{-1}$. However, notice that our boundary condition can be rearranged to $y_{-1} = 2h + y_1$. Substituting this and $y_0=2$ into the difference equation yields
$$
(1+h)y_1 + 2(h^2-2) + (1-h)(2h+y_1)=0,
$$
which is a linear equation for $y_1$. Since the boundary conditions was discretized using a second order scheme, we actually retain second order accuracy of the finite difference scheme, which is lost if you approximate the boundary condition with a simple one-sided difference.